# How to persist file references? (HTML5 File API)

Tags: javascript, html

On http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ it says:

> As example of its capabilities, the File API could be used to create a thumbnail preview of images as they're being sent to the server, or allow an app to save a file reference while the user is offline.

I cannot find any information about how it works to save a file reference while the user is offline. Is there a possibility to solve this problem? Where can I find information about it?

Comment: Come now, always check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/), https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications